# GWT - Best way to implement a horizontal navbar

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

What is the best way to implement a horizontal navbar in GWT? Using a MenuBar, a TabLayoutPanel, or coding something by hand, that is take a bunch of `div`s an float them within another div? If played around using TabLayoutPanel but wasn't able to style it to fit my needs.

**EDIT**

Here's what I intend to do: I have a MasterPage, laid out using a DockLayoutPanel. I have a header, footer, and a content area. After login, the content are should be filled with some sort of navigation and an area showing some panel with some widgets.

Comment: This depends on what you need. Can you provide more information? A normal MenuBar looks like this: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html#menubar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with MenuBar (and MenuItems) is its rendering. GWT is rendering everything regarding menus as table and bunch of s and s. This usually messes up the layout of the rest of the page since GWT 2.0+ uses s for most of the widgets.

So, until GWT comes up with the "Layout" version for the MenuBar custom solution is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

A horizontal MenuBar works great for us.  Give each MenuItem a Command that triggers your navigation system, or just swap controls in and out of your content area directly.

A MenuBar will be more flexible than using a TabLayoutPanel, but less flexible than a bunch of custom-coded divs.